# Browser dependent issue

Tags: gwt, browser

I am using GWT-JAVA. The Login page displayed good in firefox. 
But In IE It is too slow and also Fonts are too big. 
In chrome it display only the background image. Nothing will be display. 
Is it GWT a browser dependent? Otherwise Can i change any other options or anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to show some code, or a live link. The question is hardly answerable in its current form.

Comment: I can recommend you use Ext GWT (http://www.sencha.com/products/gwt/).

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662076/google-gwt-cross-browser-support-is-it-bs (unless you change your question to a more specific one - but I'd wager it's related to CSS/box model, etc differences between browsers, than anything directly related with GWT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is intended to be browser independent, but there are limits.  Are you following the advice in the ["Cross-Browser Support"](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBrowser.html) page?

Speed of old versions of IE will always be an issue for any browser-based UI toolkit that relies heavily on Javascript.